# Mysql join table and count rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables: comments & photos

Every comments is "connected" to a certain photo by the photo id. I want to get all photos, from a certain author(author_id), and a count of all the comments on the specific photo. I'm sorry for my english, but i think that's the best way i can describe it.

I want a table with:

- id (photo table)
- rating (photo table)
- created_at (photo table)
- number_of_comments (comments table)

What i've tried so far (with syntax error):

```
"SELECT p.id, p.rating, p.created_at, x.*
FROM photos p 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT photo_id, COUNT(*) as cc
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY photo_id
) x 
ON x.photo_id= p.id"
```

error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT p.id, p.rating, p.created_at, x.* FROM photos p LEFT JOIN ( SELECT' at line 1"

photos table

- id
- author_id
- filename
- caption
- rating
- flags
- is_active

comments table

- id
- comment
- author_id
- photo_id
- created_at
- flags
- is_active

Comment: are you getting any errors ?

Comment: "What i've tried so far (with syntax error)" - can you share the error please?

Comment: There is no syntax error in your query

Comment: i just added the error to my post

Comment: Are the quotes after p.id the problem?

Comment: oh no, it's just because the statement is missing a " in the start.

Comment: Still there is no syntax error in your query. Try copying it directly from your source code here.

Comment: Oh, i dont know why it works like this, it must have been a spelling error.. Awkward. Still the answer below is much smarter than my original query. Thanks buddy!

Comment: I like your own query just as much. Especially since MySQL is known for sometimes having bad performance on aggregations. So it may well be a good idea to do the aggregation on comments first and only then join with photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a note, the fastest way to write this query is likely to be:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM comments c WHERE c.photo_id = p.id) AS cnt
FROM photos p
WHERE p.author_id = 1;
```

For best performance, create an index on `comments(photo_id)`.

I offer this because performance is mentioned as a consideration.  The `join` and `group by` method is also a good way to write the query.

Comment: This does not return what the above solution does. I want the query to return the photo info, of a certain author(author_id) AND the number of commments on the photo. Your's returns all photos. I have suggested an edit :) ty

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann . . . You would add a `where` condition if you want to get something about a particular author.  It looks like your original syntax error is due to the double quote at the beginning of the SQL statement.

Comment: Yes i figured that out :) Copy paste error it would seem. ty :)

Comment: Your query suits my problem perfectly, and since i found out the previous accepted answer actually didnt do the trick, i accepted yours as the answer.

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann in your question above you didn't ask for author_id thing, so ... :) Also this solution works only for 1 particular author. You better do `SELECT p.author_id, p.id, (SELECT count(*) ...) cnd FROM photos p WHERE p.author_id=1 (optional where clause) GROUP BY p.author_id, p.id`. That'll return each author + each photo + count of comments for each photo.

Answer (score 3):

This way it'll work much faster with less resources need and will be simpler to read :)

```
SELECT p.id, p.rating, p.created_at, count(c.id) AS cnt
FROM photos p 
    LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.photo_id=p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: you can add them in group by, but I believe they are not needed, because `p.id` is primary key which is unique for each photo.

Comment: Even though my query actually seems to work, apparently, this way is much smarter than my solution! Upvoted and will be marking this as the answer in 2 min, when i am able to. Thanks buddy

Comment: rating and created_at should be the same for every id, so MySQL wouldn't produce wrong results - and MySQL would execute the query without error.

Comment: ... and much faster, because no cursor is needed

Comment: I will also be using this solution, not mine :)

Comment: Actually if you could just edit your answer, to use WHERE p.author_id = 1, that would be the correct answer for my question :) I only want the the pictures of a certain author (user), and not all pictures.

Comment: Hmm.. i have tested it further, and it seems that your query only returns 1 row (photo), where i should be returning alle the photos for a given author.

Comment: Just add `WHERE p.author_id = 1` and it should return all photos of given author.