# How to count rows of another table in a while loop [PHP] [SQL]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, rows

I have a table which shows cities in florida.

I have another table with activities for each city, these tables are connected with a foreign key.

I have a while loop which lists the cities with an image and its population, what i want to do is to make the while loop display the amount of activities i have added in the database for that city.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahdZ7.jpg see image on top

^
I want the X to be the number of rows in the activities table sharing the city_id with the city.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahdZ7.jpg image on bottom, to make it easier to understand

I have made a while loop of the first table, but want to add number of activities**(table on right)** for that city inside the while loop and I am wondering how i can to that, this is how my current code looks like

```
<?php
include "kobling.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM city";
$resultat = $kobling->query($sql);


while ($rad=$resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
    $navn = $rad["navn"];
    $bilde = $rad["bilde"];
    $befolkning = $rad["befolkning"];



    echo '<div class="byeramme">';
    echo "<img src='$bilde' align='left' width='500px' height='250px'";
    echo "<p align='center'> $navn</p>";
    echo "<p align='center'>Antall bosatte:&nbsp $befolkning</p>";
    echo "<p align='center'> Antall attraksjoner:&nbsp X</p>";
    echo '</div>';
    } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. I guess this answer will help you to achieve what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23573680/1128918. Instead of photos and comments, you have cities and activities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql join table and count rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573598/mysql-join-table-and-count-rows)

Comment: I am a high school student so I don't know how to add that code to my own code, could you please add that code to my code and send it to me?

Comment: I guess you need some help with your homework. If that's true, maybe you're asking at the wrong place. Please refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions on how to ask homework-related questions.

Comment: It's not homework, it is a school project where I am free to add whatever I want to the website. I don't understand why you are not helping me considering how easy it would be for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need only the count of activitis you could do it with a single query eg:

```
      $sql = "SELECT city.navn as navn
             , city.bilde as bilde
             , city.befolkning as befolkning
            , count(*) as my_count
      FROM city
  LEFT JOIN  attrakjoner on city.city_id = activities.city_city_id
  GROUP BY city.city_id ";
```

then in my_count you have the number of activities

```
<?php
include "kobling.php";
      $sql = "SELECT city.navn as navn
             , city.bilde as bilde
             , city.befolkning as befolkning
            , count(*) as my_count
      FROM city
      LEFT JOIN attrakjoner  on city.city_id = activities.city_city_id
      GROUP BY city.id";
$resultat = $kobling->query($sql);


while ($rad=$resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
    $navn = $rad["navn"];
    $bilde = $rad["bilde"];
    $befolkning = $rad["befolkning"];
    $myCount = $rad["my_count"];



    echo '<div class="byeramme">';
    echo "<img src='$bilde' align='left' width='500px' height='250px'";
    echo "<p align='center'> $navn</p>";
    echo "<p align='center'>Antall bosatte:&nbsp $befolkning</p>";
    echo "<p align='center'> Antall attraksjoner:&nbsp  $myCount</p>";
    echo '</div>';
    } 
 ?>
```

Comment: In which part of my own code do I add the code you just sent?

Comment: use an outer join to allow return of a city with a zero count for events....  , `, COUNT(activities.city_id) FROM city LEFT JOIN activities ON`...

Comment: @spencer7593   .. correct  in this case left join is better  .. answer  udpated

Comment: $sql = "SELECT city.*, count(*) as my_count
      FROM city
      LEFT JOIN activities on city.id = activities.city_id
      GROUP BY city.id";

Gave me a fatal error, 
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: have you e used proper column and table name for join .? ..my column name are just a suggestion .. i don't know your table schema so you should adapt my query to you tables and columns name  ..

Comment: I adapted it already, but I think error comes from "my_count" because i dont have such a row in my database

Comment: my_count is an alias for count(*) so  .. you don't need  a column in db for this  ..  ..answer  updated using explicit column name too

Comment: I'm sorry  ..  i missing an on clause .. answer update with on keyword  too

Comment: I gave up from a while, but after spending hours I finally got it working thanks to your code. Thanks a lot for your help. Problem was that I made a spelling error in the database.